# OpenCV velocity estimation

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I was wondering if Lucas-Kanade Optical flow would be the best way to estimate the velocity of a baseball/cricketball being hit. I want to get a 3d velocity vector of the initial velocity of the ball to plug into a physics engine. Would I need 2 cameras, 1 for the x, y component and another for x/y, z Or can it be done with 1?

Comment: Could be done with a single camera by measuring the size of the ball, which is proportional to the distance. But this will be horribly inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on optical flow, this will be too noisy. Much more reliable to take the positions in two successive frames. Two cameras, stereoscopy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've researched stereoscopy I'm not sure how this would work could you explain a bit more? Sorry I'm kinda a begginer at image processing etc.

Comment: @RehanSheikh https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html